# Unable to put data in Pandas DataFrame.Whenever i try to put these two data in Pandas.It is not done

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am unable to create a Data Frame of data_list and data_1_list.Whenever i do this i do not get an error but only one line of this whole data is only shown.Pls try this in your own code.It cant be explained in words.You try to make a Data Frame and print it and you will see that it is not all printed

```
import pandas as pd 
import lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import html5lib
from selenium import webdriver    

for des in soup.find_all('div',class_='pt-2'):
    data = des.find('p',class_='mt-1').text
    data_list = []
    data_list.append(data)
    print(data_list)
for title in soup.find_all('a',class_='stretched-link'):
    data_1 = title.h2.text
    data_1_list = []
    data_1_list.append(data_1)
    print(data_1_list)
    #Unable to put data in Pandas DataFrame.Whenever i try to put these two data in Pandas.It is not done `
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have declared `empty list` inside the loop.Keep it out side the loop.

```
data_list = []
for des in soup.find_all('div', class_='pt-2'):
    data = des.find('p', class_='mt-1').text    
    data_list.append(data)
print(data_list)

data_1_list = []
for title in soup.find_all('a', class_='stretched-link'):
    data_1 = title.h2.text    
    data_1_list.append(data_1)
print(data_1_list)
```

Now you can use this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Data_1":data_list,"Data_2":data_1_list})
print(df)
```

---

**Update**

Since the data rendered by javascripts use selenium to load the data first and then use bs4 and pandas to load into DataFrame.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="path/to/chromedriver")
driver.get("https://realpython.com/search?q=web%20scraping")
time.sleep(3)
soup=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"html.parser")
title=[]
title_content=[]
for item in soup.find_all('div', class_='row')[1:]:
    title.append(item.find('a',class_='stretched-link').find_next('h2').text)
    title_content.append(item.find('p',class_='text-muted my-0 mt-1 small').text)


df = pd.DataFrame({"Data_1":title,"Data_2":title_content})
print(df)
```

**Output**:

```
                                            Data_1                                             Data_2
0                  Learning Path: Python Web Scraping  Web scraping is about downloading structured d...
1                Topic: Python Web Scraping Tutorials  Web scraping is about downloading structured d...
2    Practical Introduction to Web Scraping in Python  Learn the basics of web scraping with Python u...
3                Web Scraping with Scrapy and MongoDB  This tutorial covers how to write a Python web...
4   Web Scraping and Crawling with Scrapy and MongoDB  Part 2 in this tutorial series covers how to e...
5   The Real Python Podcast – Episode #12: Web Scr...  Do you want to get started with web scraping u...
6     Beautiful Soup: Build a Web Scraper With Python  In this tutorial, you'll walk through the main...
7      Modern Web Automation With Python and Selenium  Your guide to learning advanced Python web aut...
8                                    Course Overviews  An overview of the contents of the Real Python...
9                       The Real Python Course Bundle  Learn Python from the ground up and gain real-...
10                            What are people saying?  What the Python community says about the Real ...
11                                 Python Basics Book  Master fundamental concepts for Python beginne...
12       The Ultimate List of Python YouTube Channels  We couldn't find a good and updated list of Py...
13  Flask by Example – Text Processing with Reques...  In part three of this series, we're going scra...
14                              The Best Python Books  Find the right books to help you get started w...
15                             Python Books & Courses  At Real Python we offer a number of Python tra...
16  Switching to Python From Another Programming L...  Here you'll find the best resources and tips f...
17              How can I learn the basics of Python?  How to learn Python programming as a complete ...
18                                          Resources  Free tutorials and resources, developed by the...
19                    Learn Python Programming Online  Learn Python online: Web development tutorials...
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.I.will surely try it.

Comment: @SAYAN : I don't have the url to test.Whats the problem are you getting?

Comment: Can u tell me how to seperate lists in a list by comma?

Comment: @SAYAN : Instead of asking question if you could share your url and expected output.It would be easier to help.